# Can't debug Rails app in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine, rubymine-7

When I debug a simple rails app (only ran scaffold command). Rubymine does not show any variable in debugger window. I already installed ruby-debug-ide 0.4.30, debase 0.1.3 gems on Rubymine and I am using ubuntu 14.04, ruby 2.2 , rails 4.2.2, rbenv , rubymine 7.1 .

thanks in advance.
[image: rails app]

[image: rails app]

**Update:** Problem solved!! Just comment out the 'byebug' gem.

Comment: debugger only supports ruby 1.9.  Use byebug instead.  Did you go to the users index action in your browser?

Comment: actually I cant remember the exact gem name I installed. When I go to debug for the first time, rubymine asks me to install a gem and I install it. Yes, I check the debugger after going to index action in browser. @japed

Comment: Can you debug a simple ruby (not rails)code on your rubymine?

Comment: This is the first time I am using Rubymine. I did not try it yet. @Mourad

Comment: OK, now tell me what are the gems that you installed before debuging

Comment: Two gems, uby-debug-ide 0.4.30, debase 0.1.3 @Mourad

Comment: OK, now tell me is it obligatory to work with ruby 2.2 or you can work with another version like 1.9? Iam only asking these questions so i can give a proper answer @Junan

Comment: do you think you can work with Rails 4.X with ruby 1.9?  @Mourad

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yesterday i was not able to post my answer due to some SO problems

Answer (score 1):

To help you here are some steps to follow in order to debug in your rubyMine.

**First  Install dubug gems localy:**

1. Download  the following gems:

   - [debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.8](https://rubygems.org/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source/versions/1.3.8)
   - [ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre15](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug-base19x/versions/0.11.30.pre15)
2. Place the downloaded gems into a file called `gems`
3. Open Ruby `cmd` consol `[clic on start button, select Ruby then select  Start  command prompt with Ruby]`
4. Cd to the gems file path [lets supose the path of your gems file is `C:\Desktop\gems`] write the command: `cd C:\Desktop\gems`   then clic enter.
5. To install the first gem run the following comand: `gem install --local debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.8.gem`
6. To install the second gem run the following comand: `gem install --local ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre15.gem`
7. Restart RubyMine and test if it works now

**Second try the exact same steps with Ruby 1.9 version instead of 2.2**

Now if that doeasnt work with the 2.2 Ruby version try it with the version 1.9.
and hopefuly it will work for you because it did with me.